# How do I get a variable and image into the Lego Mindstorms EV3 image editor

Tags: ev3, mindstorms, programming

I am making a project and I want the EV3 brick to have a GUI-like interface. It also needs to display a variable on the GUI. Is there a way to draw the GUI and have the live variable reading as well? The image text block just replaces the whole image. I would like to do this without drawing out a state for every single possible variable value and then updating it to match the variable.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the program that you tried that does not work?